# Trying to open a Jupyter Notebook with Julia - ERROR (See below, please)

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, julia

Please, help me.
This so claled "Registry.toml" is the problem?
How do I fix it??

#julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
Installing known registries into `C:\Users\Julio Bruce\.julia`
ERROR: SystemError: opening file "C:\Users\Julio Bruce\.julia\registries\General\Registry.toml": No such file or directory

Comment: I have already re-installed Julia and the problem continues...

Answer (score 2):

This file is a database of Julia package registries.
Either it is corrupted or something is wrong with it's access rights.

Delete the folder
`C:\Users\Julio Bruce\.julia\`
and restart Julia.

Reinstalling does not help because it did not delete `.julia` folder. And there is no need to reinstall anyway - just delete the entire `.julia` folder.